# Find last modified file in adb shell

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb

I am trying to find last modified file through adb shell. Problem is that commands like less, head, tail, awk, cut aren't available in adb shell.

Is there any way that I can find last modified file using ls and grep only? file names are in sorted order and doing ls -l shows last modified file in the end.

Comment: Is your device rooted ?

Comment: no. but I can access its files via command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in features from shell (arrays) to achieve this:

```sh
IFS=$'\n'                    # Using only newline as delimiter (ignore tabs and spaces)
output=(`ls -l`)             # Save output as array (each position is one line)
lines=${#output[@]}          # Calculate the number of lines
echo ${output[$((lines-1))]} # Print the last line from output
```

And if you want only the filename, you could be a little more tricky:

```sh
IFS=$'\n'
output=(`ls -l`)
lines=${#output[@]}

IFS=$' '
file_line=(${output[$((lines-1))]})

file_name=()
index=0
for part in ${file_line[@]}; do
    if [[ $index -gt 4 ]]; then file_name+=($part); fi
    index=$((index+1))
done

echo ${file_name[@]}
```

I hope these will be helpful.